# C++ analogue of mapping function

Tags: c++, vector, functional-programming, standards, standard-library

I'm surprised that I didn't find `map` function in standard C++ lib. Now I'm using this solution

```
template <typename Container, typename InputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
Container filter(InputIterator _from, InputIterator _to, UnaryPredicate _pred)
{
    Container collection;
    return std::accumulate(_from, _to, collection, 
        [_pred] (Container acc, const InputIterator::value_type & val) -> Container
        {
            if (_pred(val))
                acc.insert(std::end(acc), val);
            return acc;
        });
}

//////////////////////////////
// usage

    std::vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> newVec = filter<decltype(newVec)>(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
        [] (int n)
        {
            return n % 2 == 0;
        });
```

but maybe some more *common* solution exists

---

edit : as is said below, it's filtering function. Okay, here is my `map` implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename MapFunction>
T map(T source, MapFunction func)
{
    T collection;
    for (auto val : source)
    {
        collection.insert(std::end(collection), func(val));
    }
    return collection;
}
```

so problem with `std::transform` and others that they changes source collection, but they should return another one.

Comment: Why are you asking about a `map` function while showing an implementation for a `filter`?

Comment: C++ has `std::for_each` to call a function on each element.

Comment: @juanchopanza filter is just map with predicate. Sorry for misunderstanding, for me they both are almost the same

Comment: No, filter takes many things and returns less of the same. Map applies an operation to N things, giving you N results.

Comment: you right, but in FP you don't keep in mind things such as collection size etc.

Comment: So what? My first comment still applies. Map and filter are different things, otherwise only one of them would exist.

Comment: Well, they both doesn't exists in current lib. And it's very strange imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest to the `map` (builtin of python, for example) would be `std::for_each` or `std::transform`, applying a function to a range defined by an iterators pair:

Example from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), for a transform in-place:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s("hello");
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper));
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Or a `for_each` with a lambda function, here we increment each element by 1:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};
    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ n++; });
}
```

Part of the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Note that if using `toupper`, you should ensure its argument is an `unsigned char` (or at least in the range of one). "Hello" all is unless it's some obscure character set, if that's even permitted, but that won't work in general.

Comment: @chris: Anyway, `toupper` is ill-suited for most locales.